# VS 2012 WPF XAML Designer Blank

Tags: c#, wpf

I recently converted a VS 2010 WPF project to VS 2012. However, in VS 2012 the WPF designer is blank. There is no controls, just an outline of an empty Window.

Comment: Is the XAML still there or did it end up getting removed somehow?

Comment: VS2012 is round-trippable with VS2010 SP1. Do you see the same problem if you re-open with VS2010?

Comment: The XAML is still there, when I open it up with VS 2010 it shows up fine. I am using Nuget (I installed it for VS 2012) and I am using MahApps.Metro.